# Contains () statement does not find the indicated string

Tags: vb.net, substring

I am developing a program that uses string functions in VB and in general does it well BUT I have found a case that does not work as expected.

In the following code, the content of variable `text_to_search` exists inside of `texto_base` but always returns the variable `exists = false`.

The code is very simple:

```
existe = false
If texto_base.Contains(text_to_search) Then
    existe = True
End if
```

Theses variables contains:

```
text_to_search = "se vuelven nuestros compañeros"

texto_base = "los perros son parte de la familia. se vuelven nuestros compañeros y amigos fieles. se apropian de nuestro corazón, de nuestros pensamientos y... de nuestras camas"
```

Could it be that the variable `texto_base` contains special characters that are not visually visible? Or that has a different encoding?

Note: I have tried indexof and instr with same result.

Comment: Returns `True` for me.

Comment: it works fine for me. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6EOavT

Comment: If you had pasted that string from some HTML source, it might contain *invisible* characters. Not here, though. Btw `existe = texto_base.Contains(text_to_search)`.

Comment: There could be invisible characters in there. If you copy the strings from this question and test if texto_base.Contains(text_to_search), what result do you get?

Comment: If you can find out how the invisible characters got in there and what they are (their character codes), it might be easier to find a solution.